# TypeORM 'Module not found' when building (webpack)

Tags: typescript, webpack, node-gyp, typeorm

I googled the issue for a while and found several posts on the `typeorm` github, but they were all closed without a solution provided. It seem to be a `webpack` issue, but I don't understand what the issue is exactly. The example compiles well for me.

It happens as soon as I call `createConnection`, which is imported from `typeorm`. The error I get is the following. I have cut off most of the "Can't resolve  in ..." but you get the idea.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'redis' in '/my/project/node_modules/typeorm/platform'
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
@ ./src/main.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sql.js' in '/my/project/node_modules/typeorm/platform'
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
@ ./src/main.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head>
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
@ ./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
@ ./src/main.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/Find-VS2017.cs 7:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| // Usage:
| // powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Version "2.0" -Command "&{Add-Type -Path Find-VS2017.cs; [VisualStudioConfiguration.Main]::Query()}"
> using System;
| using System.Text;
| using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
@ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib sync ^\.\/.*$ ./Find-VS2017.cs
@ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib sync ^\.\/.*$
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
@ ./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
@ ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/unpublish.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '/my/project/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/unpublish.js 16:14-32
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib sync ^\.\/.*$
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
@ ./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
@ ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/info.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '/my/project/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/info.js 14:14-32
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib sync ^\.\/.*$
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
@ ./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
@ ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '/my/project/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js 18:14-32
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib sync ^\.\/.*$
@ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
@ ./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
@ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
@ ./src/main.ts
```

My `package.json` (I removed some dependencies to shorten it a bit)

```
{
  "name": "something-with-electron",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "npm run build && electron ./dist/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js",
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^3.10.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.119",
    "@types/mime-types": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.12",
    "@types/react": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.11",
    "@types/electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "electron": "^3.0.10",
    "electron-builder": "^20.38.5",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.6",
    "standard": "^12.0.1",
    "standard-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-standard": "^8.0.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.4",
    "tslint-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.11",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

And my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const commonConfig = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: 'standard-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.jsx', '.json']
  }
}

module.exports = [
  Object.assign(
    {
      target: 'electron-main',
      entry: { main: './src/main.ts' }
    },
    commonConfig),

  Object.assign(
    {
      target: 'electron-renderer',
      entry: { gui: './src/gui.tsx' },
      plugins: [new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'something',
        template: './src/index.html'
      })]
    },
    commonConfig)
]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

i've got the same issue while i was setting up my project.

To resolve that you can add the following plugin into your webpack config in order to remove the warning for the plugin that you don't want to use

```
new FilterWarningsPlugin({
    exclude: [/mongodb/, /mssql/, /mysql/, /mysql2/, /oracledb/, /redis/, /sqlite3/, /sql.js/, /react-native-sqlite-storage/]
})
```

Hope that will help you :)

Comment: I know it is not a good solution, but this should be the accepted since it is recommended in the [official docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-to-use-webpack-for-the-backend). Ideally, the drivers should be separate modules and this feature is already in the [roadmap](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3267#issuecomment-518430129)